# Unit testing generators with `return` and `yield`

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, generator, babeljs, istanbul

**Given this function**

```
function* backflip(query) {
  return yield 123;
}
```

**And this test**

```
describe('backflip', () =>
  it('should do that ^', () =>
    let handlerInstance = handler();
    expect(handlerInstance.next().value).to.equal(123);
    expect(handlerInstance.next().done).to.equal(true);
  );
);
```

Istanbul, should say all branches are covered, but in fact this covers 3 of 4. Removing `return` fixes the problem.

- Is `return` and `yield` together an antipattern?
- Is this a bug?

**For context, Babel compiles this as**

```
"use strict";

var _marked = [backflip].map(regeneratorRuntime.mark);

function backflip(query) {
  return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function backflip$(_context) {
    while (1) {
      switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
        case 0:
          _context.next = 2;
          return 123;

        case 2:
          return _context.abrupt("return", _context.sent);

        case 3:
        case "end":
          return _context.stop();
      }
    }
  }, _marked[0], this);
}
```

Comment: How are you running annotating the code with coverage tracking?

Comment: You can see in the compile code that `case 3` is never reached. You should only be concerned about code coverage of the code you write, not the generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/590
- https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/issues/181
- [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=function*%20gen()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%207%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction*%20gen()%20%7B%0A%20%20yield%207%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction*%20gen()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20yield%207%3B%0A%7D)

It’s a bug that is being addressed. The branch is currently untestable.

Answer (score -1):

Quick example from console:

```
var g = function* backflip(query) {
    yield 123; return 0;
};
undefined
var a = g();
undefined
a.next()
Object {value: 123, done: false}
a.next()
Object {value: 0, done: true}
a.next()
Object {value: undefined, done: true}
```

Generator has 1 more state.